# Is there API support for salesforce.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, api

I'm able to use the API to get selected questions from stackoverflow.com by running
*https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=salesforce&site=stackoverflow*,
but I'd like to do something similar for https://salesforce.stackexchange.com as it has different questions.

Is there a way I can do it?
Based on *https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites*, it doesn't seem to be supported.
Am I correct?

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that /sites has multiple pages of results when determining if a site is supported or not. Salesforce appears on page 2 (with pagesize 100) https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pagesize=100&page=2

Comment: I'm speechless...
Those are my first steps with this API and I totally forgot that /sites only show max. 100 results per page.

When I run https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=salesforce&site=stackoverflow it was all fine
so I tried the same tag on salesforce site
tagged=salesforce&site=salesforce
which presented 0 results, so I though it was not supported.
Now I realized there are no questions with this tag, as it's all about salesforce, so people just tags like apex or isv, which works.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkaruz: Yeah – in general, for most/all sites, we'll block the creation of a tag that is identical to the site's name (as an "intrinsic tag" block). So `salesforce` (and similar terms like `salesforce.com`) actually *can't* be created as a tag on the Salesforce Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3):

Surely it is supported; just go to [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), scroll to Try It and click the [edit] link next to the default site, Stack Overflow, and start typing:

[image]

You'll end up with [the page telling you the right endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=salesforce&run=true), namely https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=salesforce. You can filter on tag name, but only on tags which actually [exist on the site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/).

---

That it doesn't seem to be supported from the response to the `/sites` call has the following reason. As indicated by the commenters, the Stack Exchange API makes heavy use of [pagination](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging), and the default page size is 30, so that's why the response to your call only lists that many sites. It's possible to increase this to 100 for all API calls, but that still would not return the about 180 * 2 sites (the call also returns child metas). Stack Exchange acknowledged that and [made an exception for this particular call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites):

> The `pagesize` parameter for this method is unbounded, in acknowledgement that for many applications repeatedly fetching from `/sites` would complicate start-up tasks needlessly.

[Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=1000&filter=default&run=true) you can test that all sites, including Salesforce.SE, are included in the response.